# File exchange PC <--> Android via USB MTP issues

Tags: android, file-upload, usb, mtp

In my android app, I create a file and write some test text into it:

```
File externalPath = getExternalFilesDir(null);
File importPath = new File(externalPath, "pd-import");
if(!importPath.exists()) {
    Log.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "Create import dir: " + importPath.getAbsolutePath());
    importPath.mkdirs();
}

File readme = new File(importPath, "README.txt");
try {
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(readme);
    fw.write("This is a test");
    fw.flush();
    fw.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This writes the file, which can be approved with an android file browser like *B1 File Manager*. It's written to *HOME/Android/data/JAVA_PACKAGE_NAME/files/pd-import/README.txt*
[image: Screenshot with Folder]

The logcat shows me: 
*D/MainActivity﹕ Create import dir: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/JAVA_PACKAGE_NAME/files/pd-import*

When I connect my Nexus, where I tested the code, to my Ubuntu Laptop via USB, I see all the other applications data directories like *NEXUS 5/Interner Speicher/Android/data/ALL_THE_OTHER_JAVA_PACKAGE_NAMEs* ("Interner Speicher" stands for: internal memory). But the folder is not listed for my app is not listed.

[image: Screenshot without the folder]

Do I need to set some additional medatdata/information/whatever, to have the folder listed over the MTP connection? Anny suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Does the directory appear when the device is rebooted ? If yes, I think this bug is the cause : https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=38282

> All phones using MTP instead of USB Mass storage do not properly show
>   the list of files when that phone is connected to a computer using a
>   USB cable. Android apps running on the device also cannot see these
>   files.
>
> This affects files written using Java APIs, but does not appear to
>   affect files written using the C API.
>
> The solution is to reboot the device.

It does not seem to be resolved.

Comment: @andreas Am not sure abt this , but i dont think checking with ddms file browser will help exploring through nexus device, due to security issues unless you are using emulator. But it will be surely visible with files explorer app installed in your phone.Correct me, if i am wrong or missing any points.

Comment: Hi, sorry for my late response! I got ill and was not able to test your suggestion. Maybe I am able tomorrow.